# Как узнать сколько прошло времени от последнего запуска бота?

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Пробовал через библиотеку time, но ничего не вышло.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time

start = time.monotonic()
result = time.monotonic() - start


class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def test(self, ctx):
         await ctx.send("Program time: {:>.3f}".format(result) + " seconds.")
    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Засуньте получение результата в саму функцию:

```
    async def test(self, ctx):
         result = time.monotonic() - start
         await ctx.send("Program time: {:>.3f}".format(result) + " seconds.")
```

Либо сделайте `result` функцией, тогда останется ее вызывать для получения разницы:

```
result = lambda: time.monotonic() - start
...

    async def test(self, ctx):
         await ctx.send("Program time: {:>.3f}".format(result()) + " seconds.")
```

---

Для приведения секунд в человеческий вид, можно использовать `datetime.timedelta`, пример:

```
import datetime as DT
print(DT.timedelta(seconds=10000))
# 2:46:40

print(DT.timedelta(seconds=10000000))
# 115 days, 17:46:40.900000
```

Comment: А как `result` разбить на дни, часы, минуты, секунды?

Comment: Самое простое через `datetime.timedelta` (добавлю пример в ответ), но можно руками, например так: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f0403620f7948306ad9e34a373f2aabc0237fb2a/seconds_to_str.py#L7 (там только до часов, минут и секунд делится, но можете добавить разбиение часов на дни)

Comment: Спасибо, работает